# Filter not being executed at all

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have a simple HttpServlet Filter in Tomcat 8 that I want to use on every request, and then proceed to the other servlets. But the filter is not being executed at all. Here is the web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>requestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>controller.RequestsFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>requestFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file> 
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and here is the filter:

```
@WebFilter
public class RequestsFilter extends HttpServlet implements Filter {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("RequestFilter");

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        req.setAttribute("key", "some random string");

        log.warning("**RequestFilter**");
        filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

}
```

Would appreciate any help, and thanks.

Comment: I know this isn't your problem - but just to be safe, you dont have logging set to error or anything do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **NOT** a filter.

You are **mixing up** servlet and filters. Filter and Servlet are **completely two different things.**

```
public class RequestsFilter extends HttpServlet implements Filter {
```

I can see some issues in your web.xml as well. `<servlet-name>` should not be there in  `<filter-mapping>`

```
 <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
```

You can find a simple yet clean example **[here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-filters.html)**.